# getting result in the same order it was added in the table

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE tag_by_user (
userId uuid,
tagId uuid,
colId timeuuid,
tagLabel text,
PRIMARY KEY (userId, tagId,colId)
);
```

here is my data

```
insert into tag_by_user(userId,tagId,colId,tagLabel) values(4978f728-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b
,b0b328fa-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b,now(),'html');
insert into tag_by_user(userId,tagId,colId,tagLabel) values(4978f728-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b
,b0b330d4-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b,now(),'java');
insert into tag_by_user(userId,tagId,colId,tagLabel) values(4978f728-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b
,c0f22450-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b,now(),'javascript');
insert into tag_by_user(userId,tagId,colId,tagLabel) values(4978f728-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b
,c0f226b2-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b,now(),'scala pro');
insert into tag_by_user(userId,tagId,colId,tagLabel) values(4978f728-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b
,c0f22ab8-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b,now(),'c++');
```

Now i want to get the tags of a given user in same order it was added to the row (i.e in the ascending order of time when it was added and here that one is `colId`)

```
cqlsh:ks_demo> select taglabel from tag_by_user where userid= 77c4d46c-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b  order by colid;
```

it gives this error

```
Bad Request: Order by currently only support the ordering of columns following their declared order in the PRIMARY KEY
```

What changes i will have to in schema or in query  `cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.8`

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave only userId and colId in the PRIMARY KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE tag_by_user (
userId uuid,
colId timeuuid,
tagId uuid,
tagLabel text,
PRIMARY KEY (userId, colId)
);
```

And then use

```
SELECT * FROM tag_by_user WHERE userId={yourUserId}
```

to get the tags of a given user in ascending order of time.

If you need to avoid duplicate tags, then you can create an index on tagId and use it to find out if a tag already exists for a given user and process it. Though you cannot modify `colId` once data is inserted.

Comment: will this schema able to answer `select * from tag_by_user where userId =123 and tagId=xyz`

Comment: @Manish Yes, you'll need to create an index on `tagId` for that. Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

As the message suggests, to use order by, you should follow the same order as in PRIMARY KEY.

```
CREATE TABLE tag_by_user (
    userid uuid,
    colid timeuuid,
    tagid uuid,
    taglabel text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, colid, tagid)
);

select taglabel from tag_by_user where userid = 4978f728-0f96-11e5-a6c0-1697f925ec7b  order by colid;

 taglabel
------------
       html
       java
 javascript
  scala pro
        c++
```

Comment: will this schema able to answer `select * from tag_by_user where userId =123 and tagId=xyz`

Comment: nope, for that you need to create another table with PRIMARY KEY (userid,tagid)

Comment: basically i want to check for duplication of tag before insert. so in the same schema is it possible?

Comment: In that case arystan's solution would work, just be cautious while using indexes, Refer: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html